# confirm dialog is not being called using Jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I need few customisation in confirm box in jsp which were not possible using javascript but after a bit research found that Jquery would be useful to accomplish this requirement.

Tried below code but when button click action was performed confirm box was not getting displayed, Confused and unable to understand the issue.

Below is my code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <script type="text/javascript" >

 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#docs").click(function(){
         ConfirmDialog();
     });

     });

    function ConfirmDialog(){
         $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
                      .html('<div><h6>'+"Do you want to export or open the document"+'?</h6></div>')
                     .dialog({
                            modal: true, title: '', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                            width: 'auto', resizable: false,
                            buttons: {
                                Export: function () {
                                                                   $(this).dialog("close");
                                    alert("your document is being saved");
                                },
                                Open: function () {
//                                  
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                    alert("your document will open in another window");
                                }
                            },
                            close: function (event, ui) {
                                $(this).remove();
                            }
                        });
        };




</script>

<button id="docs">xxx docs</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there any console error ? you will help us to detect the error if you post the error which is should be shown at browser console

Comment: @BasilBattikhi Thanks for reply.. No Sir no error reported in console

Comment: sir can you help me if there is any error in code like in function calling?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).appendTo(...).html(...).dialog is not a function
    at ConfirmDialog (jq.html:19)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (jq.html:11)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
ConfirmDialog @ jq.html:19
(anonymous) @ jq.html:11
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3` I got this error in console log. @BasilBattikhi, if that helps you

Comment: @YashKaranke thanks for reply... i am unable to see any error in my console. is there any setting need to be done

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the comments.
make sure that you are importing the following script

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

and they should be called before you call ConfirmDialog

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the jQuery UI library.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks sir but after using this also code is not working